Binance to Coinbase USDT transfer recovery
I transferred USDT from Binance to Coinbase and used Solana network that Coinbase does not support. I see that the transaction completed successfully. Is there a way for me to get the amount off Solana to a wallet?

I did this same thing. Have you found out anything?
